# Dificultad con TabBar en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

comentarle que estoy teniendo dificultad con mi diseno de tabBar en flutter
bueno el problema esque tengo mi diseño cuando el usuario presiona el tab y tambien tengo mi diseno estatico para cada boton cuando no esta seleccionado en ambos que es solo el borde , pero el borde y el diseno cuando esta seleccionado no cuadran, es decir no son el mismo tamano como pueden ver en la imagen que voy a subir el diseno de seleccionado es mas grande que el borde de color cafe no se si me dejo entender? en la imagen se ve mas claro, y mi idea mia esque el borde concuerde con el tamano del boton seleccionado. como ven en la imagen el borde color cafe es mas chico que el diseno de seleccionado pueden darse cuenta en el boton de MIS PUNTOS

aqui esta mi codigo:

```
 Widget _cuerpor(BuildContext contexto){

 final tamanoPhone = MediaQuery.of(contexto).size;
 return new DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child:  Container(
      width: tamanoPhone.width * 0.9,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar:  PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
              child: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.brown,
                     indicator: BoxDecoration(
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                         color: Colors.redAccent
                    ), 
                    tabs: [
                            Tab(
                                child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                            width: 1,
                                            color: Colors.brown  
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    child: Align(  
                                        alignment: Alignment.center, 
                                        child: Text("MIS PUNTOS"),
                                    ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            Tab(
                                child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                            width: 1,
                                            color: Colors.brown  
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    child: Align(  
                                        alignment: Alignment.center, 
                                        child: Text("OFERTAS"),
                                    ),
                                ),
                              ),
                          ] 

                    ),
              )
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text("Mis puntos")
                  ],
                ),
                new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text("Ofertas")
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),


      ),
    ),
  );


 }
```

Ahora otra duda mas no he podido subir los tabs al centro o quizas bajar la parte blanca que sobra en la parte superior de los tabs obviamente he intetado quitar el `preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),` a 30 o a menos valores de 50 pero ya se desbordan mis botones no se si hay una forma de subir los tabs o bajar esa parte blanca que sobra ahi.

Muchas Gracias. amigos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es así como se comporta el tab (puedes revisar el código fuente para ver que hace exactamente), por defecto toma todo el tamaño disponible y le agrega unas separaciones respectivas haciendo unos cálculos internos.

Tienes una opción que es crear tu propio tabbar ( puedes encontrar algunos ya listos en pub.dev ) , o hacer usar el fix sencillo que hice.

```dart
  int _indexSelected = 0;

    Widget _cuerpor(BuildContext contexto) {
    final tamanoPhone = MediaQuery.of(contexto).size;
    final selectedColor = Colors.redAccent;
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Container(
        width: tamanoPhone.width * 0.9,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Column(
              children: [
                TabBar(
                    onTap: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        _indexSelected = index;
                      });
                    },
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.brown,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: _indexSelected == 0
                                  ? selectedColor
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              border:
                                  Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.brown)),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text("MIS PUNTOS"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: _indexSelected == 1
                                  ? selectedColor
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              border:
                                  Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.brown)),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text("OFERTAS"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[new Text("Mis puntos")],
                      ),
                      new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[new Text("Ofertas")],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hice un update al código, no necesitas el appBar así que lo quité para evitar ese espacio en blanco que mencionabas al final.